# Docusign DateSigned value

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I'm using the DocuSign C# SDK, and building Documents programmatically.  We'd like to have a DateSigned tab which won't display any value until the signer has signed the document.  I already have a DateSigned tab on the document, but the problem is that the value for this DateSigned tab is the date the request for a signature went out (via email), and not the exact date of when the document was signed.  How can we get the DateSigned value to reflect the exact date when the document was signed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DateSigned tab is per recipient and should reflect the actual date when that particular recipient signed (see https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Tabs/Date%20Signed%20Tab.htm).
Can you confirm you're not seeing this behavior? it might be worth checking the timezone as well just in case this is related to different timezones

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer.  We were looking at getting the time when a user clicked directly on the SignHere tab, and then using that as the value for the DateSigned tab.